# VUE2 + Electron + Flask -> Python not spawning on build

Tags: vue.js, flask, electron, child-process, spawn

I've just finished my first vue+electron+flask project and I am having quite a hard time trying to package it. Everything is workig "perfectly" when using "npm run electron:serve" but when running "npm run electron:build" I do not get any error, but Flask is not launched at all. I do not really know how to fix the problem, my guess is that when building the dist folder the path to app.py is not correct, but I tried to fix it without luck.

Here is the background.js code:

```js
'use strict'

import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, { VUEJS_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }
])

async function createWindow() {
  // spawn flask app (https://medium.com/red-buffer/integrating-python-flask-backend-with-electron-nodejs-frontend-8ac621d13f72)
  var python = require('child_process').spawn('py', ['../server/app.py']);
  python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("data: ", data.toString('utf8'));
  });
  python.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`); // when error
  });
  
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1500,
    height: 1200,
    webPreferences: {
      
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      contextIsolation: !process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION
    }
  })

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }
}

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    // Install Vue Devtools
    try {
      await installExtension(VUEJS_DEVTOOLS)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString())
    }
  }
  createWindow()
})

// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    process.on('message', (data) => {
      if (data === 'graceful-exit') {
        app.quit()
      }
    })
  } else {
    process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
      app.quit()
    })
  }
}
```

The relevant part of the code calling app.py is the following:

```js
async function createWindow() {
  // spawn flask app (https://medium.com/red-buffer/integrating-python-flask-backend-with-electron-nodejs-frontend-8ac621d13f72)
  var python = require('child_process').spawn('py', ['../server/app.py']);
  python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("data: ", data.toString('utf8'));
  });
  python.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`); // when error
  });
  
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1500,
    height: 1200,
    webPreferences: {
      
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      contextIsolation: !process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION
    }
  })
```

I tried to put 3 dots insted of 2 in the app.py path ['.../server/app.py] just in case when creating the dist folder I need this extra dot to find the app.py file, but this is not working either.

My folder structure is the follwing:

- Vue-Electron

  - client

    - dist_electron
    - node_modules
    - public
    - src

      - assets
      - components
      - router
      - views
      - App.vue
      - background.js
      - main.js
      - other config files
  - server

    - data
    - env
    - app.py
    - requirements.txt
    - other python scripts imported to app.py
    - sqlite_portofolio.db

As this program will only be used by me in my personal pc, I did not want to bother using pyInstaller (I thought it would be easier to not package the python side, but if I am wrong please let me know). I would like to have a electron .exe file that I can just doble click to open the electron build and then spawn the Flask server.

Also, my feeling is that I am not killing the Flask server correctly when closing the app. I think Flask is still running when closing electron. What should I do to ensure Flask server is properly closed.

There is not a lot of information of those topics that I can follow. Any help will be aprreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

I´m having the same problem. I followed the link to this article (https://medium.com/red-buffer/integrating-python-flask-backend-with-electron-nodejs-frontend-8ac621d13f72), and it has the answer about killing the python flask server. And if you follow everything the article says, it's supposed to run the backend when opening the electron.exe, but this is not happening here on my end.

EDIT: I found the error, you need to change the path on your spawn. I sugest you to run the electron.exe on the cmd so you can see the error on it, so you will see the path that spawn is trying to run.

it´s probably:

```
var python = require('child_process').spawn('py', ['../resources/app/server/app.py']);
```

you will need to acess the app.py through [resources/app] as spawn start at the base dir of the electron build.

PS: I used electron-packeger that´s why mine need to add resources/app, and I used pyinstaller on my backend

Hope it will help you.